# Ionic Search Bar - Search result priority

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, search, ionic2

I have a set of Items in array

lets call it fruitArray.

```
fruitArray = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Tomato', 'Grape', 'Apple', 'Cherries', 'Cranberries', 'Raspberries', 'Strawberries', 'Watermelon'];
```

Now, I perform a normal search operation in Ionic.

when I type the value '**ap**' in the search box, The filtered list displays the items in the following order -

Gr**ap**e

**Ap**ple

This is normal search.

In my case, I want my list to change the order of displaying the list.

**Ap**ple

Gr**ap**e

I want to show the data item starting with my `filterValue` to display first and then the data items which have the substring as my `filterValue.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it :

In your .html, add the searchbar

```
<ion-toolbar class="subtoolbarsearch">
    <ion-searchbar autocorrect="true" placeholder="Look for a fruit" [(ngModel)]="search" (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>
```

In your .ts, use 2 variables, one containing all your fruits and the ngModel of your searchbar

```
public fruits;
public search: string = "";
```

Add a function which will set the fruits

```
getFruits(){
    this.fruits = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Tomato', 'Grape', 'Apple'];
 }
```

Call if from your constructor to initialize the fruits class variable

Finally function which is triggered when input on the searchbar

```
getItems(ev) {

    this.getFruits(); // Display all the fruits

    let val = ev.target.value; // Getting the input

    // If searchbar is empty, do nothing
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {

        // Remove unmatching fruits
        for (let i = 0; i < this.fruits.length; i++) {
          let pos1 = this.fruits[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase());
          if (pos1 == -1) {
            this.fruits.splice(i, 1); // If substring not found, we remove the fruit from displayFruits
            i--; // Do not forget to decrement i by one since we removed one element from the array
          }else if(pos1 == 0){
            // If substring is at the beginning of the fruit name, we remove the fruit from the array, and we add it at the beginning of it
            let fruit = this.fruits[i];
            this.fruits.splice(i,1);
            this.fruits.unshift(fruit);
          }
        }
    }
}
```